# Strange Angular.js behavior with Faye

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, faye

I have the following code. The code is inside the controller.

```
var client = new Faye.Client('http://localhost:9292/faye');
client.subscribe('/main', function(message) {
    console.log(message);
    $scope.messages.push(message);
    console.log($scope.messages);
});
```

Here I am using Faye to listen to channel and then to add an object to `$scope`. But when I `console.log` scope, I see that the `message` object has been added to scope, but the `DOM` is not refreshed, and Two-Way binding doesn't work.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Angular needs to trigger a digest cycle when an event occurs outside of the Angular world.  Use $apply to trigger the digest:

```
var client = new Faye.Client('http://localhost:9292/faye');
client.subscribe('/main', function(message) {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        console.log(message);
        $scope.messages.push(message);
        console.log($scope.messages);
    }
});
```